# PyCharm - Send directory to run configuration from right-click menu?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a run configuration in PyCharm with script parameters that take in a directory. Then, I have several directories (a changing number) in my project which I would like to easily be able to run this configuration on. Is there anyway to add an option to the right-click menu of directories to run the configuration passing that directory to the configuration? Or some other method which provides similar accessibility to running the configuration on a directory?

For my specific problem, I have many log directories for TensorBoard (from TensorFlow) and I would like to selectively and easily be able to start up an instance of TensorBoard running on a given directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you would run it in `pycharm` You can write your own plugin to add some functionality to the `IDE`. There is a great documentation on how to create plugins in idea/pycharm:

> http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html

We have done it before and it was a successful plugin, it really sped up the development processs. :)